# Formula to find difference in time between two values when they pass midnight?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a series of times and I am trying to find the difference in time between two values which is fine for a normal day however some times pass midnight e.g.

```
18:00 - 00:30
```

The time difference is 6 hours 30 minutes which I would like returned in a numerical value e.g. 6.5 hours. However whenever I pass midnight it is not calculating properly.

Is there anyway to work around this without having to input the dates on each value? I would like it to assume if I am between the hours of 00:00 & 08:00 then I mean the following morning and anything between 08:01 and 23:59 is from the previous day.

Comment: Are your numbers in one cell or two?

Comment: Two cells @ScottCraner

Comment: I'm trying to avoid a lot of data entry I had a possible method of giving a true statement if the time is between 00:00 & 08:00 and this works but I'm struggling with adding date/time values together is this makes sense? @sous2817

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(A1>B1,1,0)+B1-A1
```

[image]

To get the `6.5` just multiply by 24, and make the format general:

```
=(IF(A1>B1,1,0)+B1-A1)*24
```

[image]

---

Edit #2

We can get rid of the IF as the expression `(A1>B1)` will return 1/0.

[image]

```
=((A1>B1)+B1-A1)*24
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, but your solution is actually much better so have an upvote.

Comment: Yes that seems to work for part of it, is there a way to convert either (15, 30 or 45) to .25, .5, .75? That way I can get it as a numerical value to total up.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but I did mention in the first line of the second paragraph that I wanted it returned as a numerical value e.g. 6 hours 30 mins to 6.5

Comment: Yeah I saw it, but jeeped answered before I can fix. @AlanTreanor

Comment: Thanks @Scott Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

Try it as,

```
=ABS(SUM(A2, -(B2+(B2<TIME(8, 0, 0)))))*24
```

... which leaves `6.5` as 6 (integer) representing hours and .5 (decimal) representing 30 minutes.

[image]